# Tracing recursive linked list?

Tags: python, recursion, trace

I'll give a simple example:

```
def find2_rec(head, o):
    '''(LLNode, obj) -> LLNode
    '''
    if head == None:
        result = (None, None)
    elif head.data == o:
        result = (head, None)
    else:
        (at_node, before_node) = find2_rec(head.next, o)
        if head.next == at_node != None:
            before_node = head
        result = (at_node, before_node)
    return result
```

Consider you are given the LLNode, which is just data and next. This function just returns the node that the object and its previous one for instance a linked list that is

```
a = [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5]
```

find2_rec(a,3) ->

```
([3] -> [4] -> [5], [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5])
```

Is the output. My question is how do I trace this?

I'm use to normal recursion were I like write it out like this:

(Basic recursive sum of list example)

```
rsum([1,2,3])
    rsum([2,3])
        rsum([3])
            return 3 
        return 5 # 3 + 2
   return 6 # 1 + 5
```

Now whats the most appropiate way to do this for LL?

Example on what I am looking for:

```
a = [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5]
```

Lets say for find2_rec(a, 3) again I would trace this as

```
[1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5]
       [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5]
              [3] -> [4] -> [5]
                  return [3] -> [4] -> [5], None
           return ([3] -> [4] -> [5], [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5])
    return ([3] -> [4] -> [5], [2] -> [3] -> [4] -> [5])
```

This is too much writing for something so small. Is there a better way?

Comment: is this for the sake of visualizing the execution? I don't think I understand what you actually want.

Comment: Yes. It helps me understand.

Comment: generally I point people to [python tutor](http://pythontutor.com) for visualization stuff, still not completely clear on what you are looking for but I'm sure that will help.

Comment: I gave an example. Python tutors goes through every step which is very very slow is there a faster way?

Comment: you can probably get something like that from python tutor by putting a break point at the return statement (click on it at execution page) but from actual code couldn't you do that by putting a print statement at the beginning of the function showing the `head` argument then another right before the return showing what it is returning?  (maybe also an `indent` argument that adds spacing to print and is incremented for recursive calls)